# downloading large file throws OutOfMemoryError in production env

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot, jhipster

Env
jhipster, angular 5,
spring boot

My app has upload and download file facility.  files are stored in db as binary blob.

I am able to download small files.  However, large files, say 35M, are getting this error. (these large files are uploaded by the app)

As per the stack trace, java.util.Arrays.copyOf is throwing the error.  hibernate calls this array fn.  I assume binary data (in blob) of 35M is attempted to be placed in array which can hold around 2M.

Is there a work around or fix to handle large data?  Can we tell hibernate to chunk the data into bits?

Scanning thru the stack trace also gave a pointer to com.neemshade.sniper.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36)
The line 36 is

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);  <-- this code
    }
```

If this filter is the origin of error, can it be hibernate issue?

Description of my code.  afterDownload() invokes server api to download binary.  Once data is available, saveToLocal() is invoked to pop-up a "Save as" dialog to store the binary data in a file.

Here is my client side code :

```
afterDownload(event) {
      this.pending = true;

      this.extTaskService.downloadFiles(this.source, this.id, this.selectedTasks)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.jhiAlertService.success('success! downloaded files. ');
          console.log(data);
          this.saveToLocal(data);
          this.uponCompletion(true);
          this.pending = false;
        },
        (err) => {
          this.jhiAlertService.error('error in download! ' + err.message, null, null);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          this.pending = false;
        },
        () => this.jhiAlertService.success('downloaded files', null, null)
      );
    }

  saveToLocal(response) {
    console.log('inside saveToLocal');
    const ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
    const ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET/g); // IE 11+
    const oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    const fileName = 'files.zip';

    if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
      console.log('got to ie');
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log('onloadend');
        window.location.href = reader.result;
      };
      console.log('readAsDataURL');
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
```

the client service :

```
downloadFiles(source: string, id: number, selectedTasks: Task[]): Observable<any> {
    const finalUrl: string = this.resourceUrl + 'download-files/' + source + '/' + id + '/' +
           (selectedIds == null || selectedIds === '' ? '0' : selectedIds);
    return this.http.get(finalUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

server side :
extDownloaderService.downloadFiles() prepares the output binary data.  I flush the data in small chunks to the response.

```
@GetMapping(value="download-files/{source}/{id}/{selectedIds}", produces="application/zip")
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadFiles(
            @PathVariable String source, @PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,
            @PathVariable(value = "selectedIds") String selectedIds, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        byte[] bytes = extDownloaderService.downloadFiles(source, id, selectedIds);

//      headers.add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"files.zip\"");

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream byteIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);


            byte[] buf=new byte[8192];
            int bytesread = 0, bytesBuffered = 0;
            while( (bytesread = byteIs.read( buf )) > -1 ) {
                os.write( buf, 0, bytesread );
                bytesBuffered += bytesread;
                if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { //flush after 1MB
                    bytesBuffered = 0;
                    os.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (os != null) {
                os.flush();
            }
        }

        os.close();

//      return new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
       }
```

When running the app with large fie, I get this stack trace.

> @400000005aaeaf751478b324 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space @400000005aaeaf751478baf4       at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(java.base@9-internal/Arrays.java:3744)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478bedc       at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(java.base@9-internal/AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478bedc       at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(java.base@9-internal/AbstractStringBuilder.java:510)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478c2c4       at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.base@9-internal/StringBuilder.java:141)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478ca94       at
>   java.util.Arrays.toString(java.base@9-internal/Arrays.java:4958)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478ca94       at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.extractLoggableRepresentation(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:63)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478ce7c       at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.extractLoggableRepresentation(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:26)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478de1c       at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.toLoggableString(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:296)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478e204       at
>   org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.toLoggableString(TypeHelper.java:439)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478e204       at
>   org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.(StandardCacheEntryImpl.java:60)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478e9d4       at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$StandardCacheEntryHelper.buildCacheEntry(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5307)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478edbc       at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildCacheEntry(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4307)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478edbc       at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:196)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478f58c       at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478f58c       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478f974       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209)
>   @400000005aaeaf751478fd5c       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514790cfc       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514790cfc       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>   @400000005aaeaf75147910e4       at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
>   @400000005aaeaf75147918b4       at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514791c9c       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514791c9c       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
>   @400000005aaeaf751479246c       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>   @400000005aaeaf751479246c       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514792854       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
>   @400000005aaeaf75147937f4       at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514793bdc       at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514793bdc       at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1122)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514793fc4       at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:646)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514794f64       at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
>   @400000005aaeaf7514794f64       at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:165)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't read the file in to memory.. Stream it directly to the `OutputStream` instead.`

Comment: the binary data is from db.  It is stored as a blob.  I am taking that and streaming to the response

Comment: @M.Deinum, is there a way to get the blob field from the db as a stream?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you tried it or not but try following solutions,

Solution - 1 : Max size which you allow to upload file, which mention in your configuration file. If it's not defined or size is less then increase it(Set it as per your requirements).

```
#Multipart
spring.http.multipart.enable=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
```

Solution - 2 : If you're using spring boot then it gives you a facility to send file as resource. So try following way,

```
Path path = Paths.get(<directory-path>).normalize();
Path filePath = path.resolve(fileName).normalize();
Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
Return ResponseEntity.ok
        .contentType(MediaType.<MIME-Type>)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, “attachment; filename=””+ resource.filename())
        .body(resource);
```

Return type of this method : `ResponseEntity<Resource>`

Solution - 3 : On the server or the system on which you upload your code which are not allowing you upload large size file, there is some **permission or restriction on your server** so contact it with your system support team (I don't have clear idea regarding this because i do that at least 0.6 year before)